# Does super saiyan god Vegeta exist in the anime series continuity?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-movies

As we know super saiyan god Vegeta appeared in the manga but not in the anime series. This could mean super saiyan god Vegeta doesn't exist in the anime, since there are concepts and elements from the anime which indeed don't exist in the manga, for example, Trunks super saiyan rage transformation or Vegeta super saiyan blue evolution transformation were created for the anime only, and elements from the manga which don't exist in the anime, for example, the mastered super saiyan blue transformation. But now we know super saiyan god Vegeta is going to appear in the Broly movie, and it isn't just concept art, there is already a screen-capture from upcoming the movie

[image: Screen Capture of Upcoming Movie]

What does this mean? Does it mean the movie is following the manga continuity (since SSG Vegeta only appeared in the manga continuity) and that we could see a mastered super saiyan blue Vegeta for example, but not a super saiyan blue evolution Vegeta, or since this is also animated media does this mean super saiyan god Vegeta also exists in the anime series (in spite of we never saw it) and that the movie either will follow the anime series continuity or a mix of the anime and manga continuities?

Answer (score 2):

While the anime & manga share a few differences like those you mentioned, the main plot and storyline are essentially the same. I believe the movie is definitely a continuation of the anime and the manga might perhaps have its own adaptation of the Broly arc after.

- If you watch the trailer, it is clearly established that the movie is set after the Tournament of Power. Hence, we know for a fact that it is a sequel to the series.
- In the end of the trailer where Goku seems to be battle damaged and Broly is transforming into his Legendary Super Saiyan form, we see Goku powerup in Super Saiyan Blue. However, in the manga, Goku's strongest form is Mastered Super Saiyan Blue. This transformation does not have any aura and wouldn't be as appealing visually.
- There is really no reason why Vegeta cannot use the Super Saiyan God Transformation. The Super Saiyan Blue (SSGSS), is essentially a combination of Super Saiyan God and Super Saiyan. Hence,  the anime could still have Vegeta use the transformation without any difficulty.

The Manga & the Anime essentially have the exact same storyline like I said earlier. In a DBS manga [interview](https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/7a0lff/dbs_manga_volume_4_full_toriyamatoyotar%C5%8D_interview/) with Toyataro and Toriyama, he did comment on Supervising Toyataro's ideas on Super Saiyan God Vegeta which indicates that he clearly isn't opposed to it. The story for the movie is again being written by Toriyama. Hence, I think it is fair to assume that with regard to transformations and few manga/anime exclusives, the anime exclusives will be adapted in the upcoming movie.